# Read or write a 8bit register in MSP432P4111 / Telemetry System with CC1200

Tags: c, embedded, spi, msp432

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * @fn          trx8BitRegAccess
 *
 * @brief       This function performs a read or write from/to a 8bit register
 *              address space. The function handles burst and single read/write
 *              as specified in addrByte. The function assumes that chip is ready.
 *
 * input parameters
 *
 * @param       accessType - Specifies if this is a read or write and if it's
 *                           a single or burst access. Bitmask made up of
 *                           RADIO_BURST_ACCESS/RADIO_SINGLE_ACCESS/
 *                           RADIO_WRITE_ACCESS/RADIO_READ_ACCESS.
 * @param       addrByte - address byte of register.
 * @param       pData    - data array
 * @param       len      - Length of array to be read(TX)/written(RX)
 *
 * output parameters
  
 uint8 trx8BitRegAccess(uint8 accessType, uint8 addrByte, uint8 *pData, uint16 len)
{
  uint8 readValue;

  /* Pull CS_N low and wait for SO to go low before communication starts */
  TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN();
  
  while(TRXEM_PORT_IN & TRXEM_SPI_MISO_PIN);
  /* send register address byte */
  TRXEM_SPI_TX(accessType|addrByte);
  TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_DONE();
  /* Storing chip status */
  readValue = TRXEM_SPI_RX();
  trxReadWriteBurstSingle(accessType|addrByte,pData,len);
  TRXEM_SPI_END();
  /* return the status byte value */

  return(readValue);
}

#define TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN()              st( TRXEM_PORT_OUT &= ~TRXEM_SPI_SC_N_PIN; NOP(); )
#define TRXEM_SPI_TX(x)                st( UCB0IFG &= ~UCRXIFG; UCB0TXBUF= (x); )
#define TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_DONE()          st( while(!(UCB0IFG & UCRXIFG)); )
#define TRXEM_SPI_RX()                 UCB0RXBUF
#define TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_MISO_LOW(x)     st( uint8 count = 200; \
                                           while(TRXEM_PORT_IN & TRXEM_SPI_MISO_PIN) \
                                           { \
                                              __delay_cycles(5000); \
                                              count--; \
                                              if (count == 0) break; \
                                           } \
                                           if(count>0) (x) = 1; \
                                           else (x) = 0; )

#define TRXEM_SPI_END()                st( NOP(); TRXEM_PORT_OUT |= TRXEM_SPI_SC_N_PIN; )
```

The problem is that all the macros #define TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN()              st( TRXEM_PORT_OUT &= ~TRXEM_SPI_SC_N_PIN; NOP(); ) and so on is not correct for the MSP432P4111 and I did not find any other documentation for that function. These functions have been written for msp430f5438a and the transition to MSP432 does not seem just easy to me.
So if somebody is familiar with the MSP432P4111 or in general with MSP432 and specifically with the SPI it would be awesome to give me an insight. Also, if you would like to know what is my whole project, it is about building a telemetry system with MSP432P4111 and the transceivers CC1200 from Texas Instruments. Something last is that for the coding I am using the Code Composer Studio.

Comment: So just ditch that ugly macro language and write straight to the registers? It's just a thin (obscure) layer above the direct register access. SPI isn't rocket science... though the initialization code seems to be missing. Getting the CPOL and CPHA settings right is usually the tricky parts, as well as non-standard timing requirements from the slave, if any.

Comment: Maybe you should look into the TI sysconfig tool and the TI MSP432 SDK on how to configure the SPI and how to use it, Since TI has no technical reference on their site, it's hard to say, what needs to be done.